# How to stop the page from refreshing on submitting form?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the details of the student to the firebase database. when I click the **create** button the page gets refreshed even though I've used **e.preventDefault()** in the javaScript.
What is wrong here?

HTML

```
<div id="Add" class="workspace">
        <h2 class="create">Enter Candidate Details</h2>
        <form id="stu-det-form">
        <input class="text1" id="cname" name="name" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Full Name" required/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cfname" name="fname" align="center" placeholder="Enter Father's Name" required/>
        <input class="text1" type="date" id="cdob" name="dob" align="center" placeholder="Enter DOB DD/MM/YYYY" required/><br>
        <select class="select1" id="cgender" name="gender">
            <option value="-Gender-">Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Undisclosed">Undisclosed</option>
        </select>
        <input class="text1" id="caddr" name="addr"align="center"  placeholder="Enter Candidate Address" required/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cphno" name="phno" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Contact Number" required/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="ceid" name="eid" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Email Address" required/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cpwd" name="pwd" align="center" placeholder="Enter Password" required/><br>
        <button class="btn-mar" id="add_btn">Create</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const studet = document.querySelector('#stu-det-form');
studet.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const name = document.getElementById("cname").value;
db.collection("candidates").doc(name).set({
  name: studet.name.value,
  fname: studet.fname.value,
  dob: studet.dob.value,
  gender: studet.gender.value,
  addr: studet.addr.value,
  phno: studet.phno.value,
  eid: studet.eid.value,
  pwd: studet.pwd.value
})
.then(function(docRef) {
  window.alert("Student Added Successfully");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    window.alert("Error Adding Student");
}); 
studet.reset();
});
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out as being obviously wrong there (well, not that could cause that problem you describe).  Have you checked the console for errors? Could `studet` be `null`?

Comment: How does the JavaScript get executed? If you just have that code sitting inside a script tag I'll bet it's running before the DOM is ready.

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the form to submit then, a better approach will be to rather than attaching event to form submission, add onclick event to your button and run your Javascript inside it.

```html
<button class="btn-mar" id="add_btn" onclick="addStud()">Create</button>
```

```js
function addStud(){
const studet = document.querySelector('#stu-det-form');

const name = document.getElementById("cname").value;
db.collection("candidates").doc(name).set({
  name: studet.name.value,
  fname: studet.fname.value,
  dob: studet.dob.value,
  gender: studet.gender.value,
  addr: studet.addr.value,
  phno: studet.phno.value,
  eid: studet.eid.value,
  pwd: studet.pwd.value
})
.then(function(docRef) {
  window.alert("Student Added Successfully");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    window.alert("Error Adding Student");
}); 
studet.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is absolutely fine. It seems you have not referenced your Javascript file into you HTML. If this is the case, use the **script** tag at the bottom of your HTML file (just above the closing `</body>` tag). Give the relative path of your  Javascript file within the src attribute.

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

There is no other reason, I found here, as your code seems fine.

```js
const studet = document.querySelector('#stu-det-form');
console.log("Within the js document");
studet.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  console.log("Form Submitted");
e.preventDefault();
const name = document.getElementById("cname").value;

// studet.reset();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Add" class="workspace">
        <h2 class="create">Enter Candidate Details</h2>
  
        <form id="stu-det-form">
        <input class="text1" id="cname" name="name" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Full Name"/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cfname" name="fname" align="center" placeholder="Enter Father's Name"/>
        <input class="text1" type="date" id="cdob" name="dob" align="center" placeholder="Enter DOB DD/MM/YYYY"/><br>
        <select class="select1" id="cgender" name="gender">
            <option value="-Gender-">Gender</option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
            <option value="Undisclosed">Undisclosed</option>
        </select>
        <input class="text1" id="caddr" name="addr"align="center"  placeholder="Enter Candidate Address"/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cphno" name="phno" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Contact Number"/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="ceid" name="eid" align="center" placeholder="Enter Candidate Email Address"/><br>
        <input class="text1" id="cpwd" name="pwd" align="center" placeholder="Enter Password"/><br>
        <button class="btn-mar" id="add_btn">Create</button>
        </form>
</div>
<!-- Use script tag to reference your javascript file :) 
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the javascript references are fine, still the page keeps refreshing.Instead of submit using a click event does the job. Thank You.

Comment: There is an event DOMContentLoaded, try using this event in your javascript file, see some docs... This event makes sure once all the DOM is loaded and only then run the javascript file... Do some debugging in developer console to check what is happening .. Is the DOM Loading correctly... No matter what, preventDefault() prevents the default behaviour of HTML tags like <a>, <form> etc... That has to work... Even then, if couldn't figure out the issue , share your code link with me on jsfiddle and I'll try to debug it for you :) Thanks